# Python built-in sum function vs. for loop performance

Tags: python, performance, sum

I noticed that Python's built-in `sum` function is roughly 3x faster than a for loop when summing a list of 1 000 000 integers:

```
import timeit

def sum1():
    s = 0
    for i in range(1000000):
        s += i
    return s

def sum2():
    return sum(range(1000000))

print 'For Loop Sum:', timeit.timeit(sum1, number=10)
print 'Built-in Sum:', timeit.timeit(sum2, number=10)

# Prints:
# For Loop Sum: 0.751425027847
# Built-in Sum: 0.266746997833
```

Why is that? How is `sum` implemented?

Comment: `sum` is implemented in C inside the Python interpreter, while your for loop has to be interpreted, it's normal that it's slower.

Comment: In *CPython* built-in functions are much faster than the pure-python translation. This is why you a good way to optimize, *for CPython*, is to let built-in functions do as much work as possible. Note that this changes completely using other implementations, such as PyPy.

Comment: What about using numpy? You of course would need to make the array first, so for a one-time use, I think it's a bit (a bunch) slower; but if you've already got the array handy, I think `arr.sum()` is faster.

Comment: @dwanderson I don't know whether it would be slower even on a one-time use. Getting the value from a number is quite easy and efficient, so creating the array will probably take less time than summing the numbers (which requires also performing additions). Then computing the sum should take *much* less time, so it might be faster. However numpy has one big problem: it uses fixed-size integers, so with long arrays it can easily overflow or you have to use an array of `object`s, which would decrease the performances a lot.

Comment: @Bakuriu: see my answer. It is *much* faster at least with large data.

Comment: @DrV dwanderson and I were speaking of dealing with the summation of a *python list* (which can be arbitrary, `range` is just one case [and a useless one too]) converting the list first to an array and then calling `.sum()`. In your answer you don't profile this case, which is what matters. It's not always possible to use a numpy array from the start for different reasons, so you must take into account the time to convert from python list to array.

Comment: @Bakuriu: I did not mention that case, because it is awfully slow. I edited it into my answer. It is quite funny it is so slow, as the data is exactly in the same form in memory. A simple memory allocation and copy should not take that much time. I guess `numpy` cannot access the raw form of `list` but is forced to use slow access methods. Pity, this has bitten me too many times.

Comment: @DrV Note that integers are *objects* in python. So the list is actually an array of pointers to `struct`s that contain a field that has the integer value, so there's a lot of dereferencing to be done. Also it should be *much* faster in python2 with lists of small `int`s instead of `long`s. In python3 all integers are `long`s and thus a conversion is necessary to obtain the actual value, which might be costly.  In any case: creating a numpy array from a list of integer is *not* a simple copy of a C array.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The speed difference is actually greater than 3 times, but you slow down either version by first creating a huge in-memory list of 1 million integers. Separate that out of the time trials:

```
>>> import timeit
>>> def sum1(lst):
...     s = 0
...     for i in lst:
...         s += i
...     return s
... 
>>> def sum2(lst):
...     return sum(lst)
... 
>>> values = range(1000000)
>>> timeit.timeit('f(lst)', 'from __main__ import sum1 as f, values as lst', number=100)
3.457869052886963
>>> timeit.timeit('f(lst)', 'from __main__ import sum2 as f, values as lst', number=100)
0.6696369647979736
```

The speed difference has risen to over 5 times now.

A `for` loop is executed as interpreted Python bytecode. `sum()` loops entirely in C code. The speed difference between interpreted bytecode and C code is large.

In addition, the C code makes sure not to create new Python objects if it can keep the sum in C types instead; this works for `int` and `float` results.

The Python version, disassembled, does this:

```
>>> import dis
>>> def sum1():
...     s = 0
...     for i in range(1000000):
...         s += i
...     return s
... 
>>> dis.dis(sum1)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (0)
              3 STORE_FAST               0 (s)

  3           6 SETUP_LOOP              30 (to 39)
              9 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (range)
             12 LOAD_CONST               2 (1000000)
             15 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             18 GET_ITER            
        >>   19 FOR_ITER                16 (to 38)
             22 STORE_FAST               1 (i)

  4          25 LOAD_FAST                0 (s)
             28 LOAD_FAST                1 (i)
             31 INPLACE_ADD         
             32 STORE_FAST               0 (s)
             35 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           19
        >>   38 POP_BLOCK           

  5     >>   39 LOAD_FAST                0 (s)
             42 RETURN_VALUE
```

Apart from the interpreter loop being slower than C, the `INPLACE_ADD` will create a new integer object (past 255, CPython caches small `int` objects as singletons).

You can see the [C implementation](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/f2e6c33ce3e9/Python/bltinmodule.c#l2327) in the Python mercurial code repository, but it explicitly states in the comments:

```c
/* Fast addition by keeping temporary sums in C instead of new Python objects.
   Assumes all inputs are the same type.  If the assumption fails, default
   to the more general routine.
*/
```

Comment: Unless you have 64-bit C longs, the sum will pretty quickly outgrow what the special case for ints can handle.

Comment: +1 for the mention of the singletons. Back when I started, I made the mistake of checking number equality with `is` and was surprised that sometimes it worked. Now though, I'm seeing that, say, `65536 is 65536` returns `True`, `1<<16 is 1<<16` returns `False`, and `1<<8 is 1<<8` returns `True`, so I guess it goes to 256? And special-cases hardcoded numbers? I'm actually more confused now...

Comment: @user2357112: Check the source; the loop for the integer case starts with `long i_result = PyInt_AS_LONG(result)`. The moment it overflows, it switches back to using Python `long` objects.

Comment: @dwanderson: Python *also* creates constants in compiled bytecode for any immutable literal values you use in code (even in the interactive interpreter). That extends to many calculated constants too, but not for `<<` bitwise shifting.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I know. I'm saying that the int special case probably doesn't have a major impact on performance here, since we exit it about 6% of the way through the list.

Comment: Ahh ok, thanks! I'll need to go get more familiar with `dis`, since it seems useful to know about how the bytecode is working under the hood

Comment: @dwanderson: you see this in the disassembly in this answer too; `LOAD_CONST` is used for the `1000000` value for the loop.

Comment: @user2357112: no, `sum(range(1000000))` fits well within my `sys.maxint` value.

Comment: @user2357112: for a 32-bit platform you are correct, you hit `sys.maxint` after about 9%.

Answer (score 5):

As `dwanderson` suggested, Numpy is one alternative. It is, indeed, if you want to do some maths. See this benchmark:

```
import numpy as np

r = range(1000000)       # 12.5 ms
s = sum(r)               # 7.9 ms

ar = np.arange(1000000)  # 0.5 ms
as = np.sum(ar)          # 0.6 ms
```

So both creating the list and summing it is much faster with `numpy`. This is mostly because the `numpy.array` is designed for this and is much more efficient than the list.

However, if we have a python list, then `numpy` is very slow, as its conversion from a list into a `numpy.array` is sluggish:

```
r = range(1000000)
ar = np.array(r)         # 102 ms
```

Answer (score 3):

However if the loop is just adding 1 each iteration starting from 0 you could use the fast trick addition. The sum output should be 499999500000 for range(1000000)

```
import timeit

def sum1():
    s = 0
    for i in range(1000000):
        s += i
    #print s    
    return s

def sum2():

    return sum(range(1000000))

def sum3():
    s = range(1000000)
    s = ((s[1]+s[-1])/2) * (len(s)-1)
    #print(s)
    return s

print 'For Loop Sum:', timeit.timeit(sum1, number=10)
print 'Built-in Sum:', timeit.timeit(sum2, number=10)
print 'Fast Sum:', timeit.timeit(sum3, number=10)

#prints
#For Loop Sum: 1.8420711
#Built-in Sum: 1.1081646
#Fast Sum: 0.3191561
```

Comment: The sum3 loop is quite helpful in this case as it computes the sum in `O(1)` time. but it can only be used for some problems.

Answer (score 1):

You can see the source code in [`Python/bltinmodule.c`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/f2e6c33ce3e9/Python/bltinmodule.c#l2295). It has special cases for `int`s and `float`s, but since the sum overflows to `long`s pretty quickly, that probably doesn't have a major performance impact here. The general-case logic is pretty similar to what you'd write in Python, just in C. The speedup is most likely due to the fact that it doesn't have to go through all the bytecode interpreting and error handling overhead:

```
static PyObject*
builtin_sum(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
{
    PyObject *seq;
    PyObject *result = NULL;
    PyObject *temp, *item, *iter;

    if (!PyArg_UnpackTuple(args, "sum", 1, 2, &seq, &result))
        return NULL;

    iter = PyObject_GetIter(seq);
    if (iter == NULL)
        return NULL;

    if (result == NULL) {
        result = PyInt_FromLong(0);
        if (result == NULL) {
            Py_DECREF(iter);
            return NULL;
        }
    } else {
        /* reject string values for 'start' parameter */
        if (PyObject_TypeCheck(result, &PyBaseString_Type)) {
            PyErr_SetString(PyExc_TypeError,
                "sum() can't sum strings [use ''.join(seq) instead]");
            Py_DECREF(iter);
            return NULL;
        }
        Py_INCREF(result);
    }

#ifndef SLOW_SUM
    /* Fast addition by keeping temporary sums in C instead of new Python objects.
       Assumes all inputs are the same type.  If the assumption fails, default
       to the more general routine.
    */
    if (PyInt_CheckExact(result)) {
        long i_result = PyInt_AS_LONG(result);
        Py_DECREF(result);
        result = NULL;
        while(result == NULL) {
            item = PyIter_Next(iter);
            if (item == NULL) {
                Py_DECREF(iter);
                if (PyErr_Occurred())
                    return NULL;
                return PyInt_FromLong(i_result);
            }
            if (PyInt_CheckExact(item)) {
                long b = PyInt_AS_LONG(item);
                long x = i_result + b;
                if ((x^i_result) >= 0 || (x^b) >= 0) {
                    i_result = x;
                    Py_DECREF(item);
                    continue;
                }
            }
            /* Either overflowed or is not an int. Restore real objects and process normally */
            result = PyInt_FromLong(i_result);
            temp = PyNumber_Add(result, item);
            Py_DECREF(result);
            Py_DECREF(item);
            result = temp;
            if (result == NULL) {
                Py_DECREF(iter);
                return NULL;
            }
        }
    }

    if (PyFloat_CheckExact(result)) {
        double f_result = PyFloat_AS_DOUBLE(result);
        Py_DECREF(result);
        result = NULL;
        while(result == NULL) {
            item = PyIter_Next(iter);
            if (item == NULL) {
                Py_DECREF(iter);
                if (PyErr_Occurred())
                    return NULL;
                return PyFloat_FromDouble(f_result);
            }
            if (PyFloat_CheckExact(item)) {
                PyFPE_START_PROTECT("add", Py_DECREF(item); Py_DECREF(iter); return 0)
                f_result += PyFloat_AS_DOUBLE(item);
                PyFPE_END_PROTECT(f_result)
                Py_DECREF(item);
                continue;
            }
            if (PyInt_CheckExact(item)) {
                PyFPE_START_PROTECT("add", Py_DECREF(item); Py_DECREF(iter); return 0)
                f_result += (double)PyInt_AS_LONG(item);
                PyFPE_END_PROTECT(f_result)
                Py_DECREF(item);
                continue;
            }
            result = PyFloat_FromDouble(f_result);
            temp = PyNumber_Add(result, item);
            Py_DECREF(result);
            Py_DECREF(item);
            result = temp;
            if (result == NULL) {
                Py_DECREF(iter);
                return NULL;
            }
        }
    }
#endif

    for(;;) {
        item = PyIter_Next(iter);
        if (item == NULL) {
            /* error, or end-of-sequence */
            if (PyErr_Occurred()) {
                Py_DECREF(result);
                result = NULL;
            }
            break;
        }
        /* It's tempting to use PyNumber_InPlaceAdd instead of
           PyNumber_Add here, to avoid quadratic running time
           when doing 'sum(list_of_lists, [])'.  However, this
           would produce a change in behaviour: a snippet like

             empty = []
             sum([[x] for x in range(10)], empty)

           would change the value of empty. */
        temp = PyNumber_Add(result, item);
        Py_DECREF(result);
        Py_DECREF(item);
        result = temp;
        if (result == NULL)
            break;
    }
    Py_DECREF(iter);
    return result;
}
```