# Most efficient way to calculate this sum in python

Tags: python, numpy, optimization

Let's say I have a list "A" of length about 40, consisting of integers from 0 to 5, and a list "Score".  I want to calculate the sum of Score[A[i]].

Of course, I can do:

```
sum = 0 
for x in A do:
    sum += Score[x]
```

But is there a faster way?  I know that numpy can do multiplication of lists, but this requires some sort of indexing.

Comment: What sucks in  `sum(Score[A[i]])`

Comment: You could try `total = sum(Score[x] for x in A)`  `sum()` is a builtin function.

Comment: (Because you tagged this [numpy]) If `Score` is a NumPy array you'd use `Score[A].sum()`. No particular reason to use this over native Python methods if you don't need other NumPy functions though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see those solutions :

```
print sum(Score[x] for x in A)
print sum(map(lambda x: Score[x], A))
```

Comment: Both `Score` and `A` are lists so I don't think your code works as it's written.

Comment: No worries - that works now, although it's probably faster to use just a generator expression in `sum`, i.e. `sum(Score[x] for x in A)`

Comment: Thanks for this.  But what if Score is different for each element, in other words, it's the sum of Score[i][A[i]].  Would I write sum(Score[i][A[i]]), or is there a faster way?

Comment: Except numpy, I don't see any faster way than sum and a generator expression. I read numpy is faster but you must define your array with numpy. [See DrV's answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24578896/python-built-in-sum-function-vs-for-loop-performance).

Answer (score 1):

The Python function "sum" is pretty efficient. It avoids memory overhead (I believe it is written in C) and should be a bit faster.

It would look like this

```
intSum = sum(array)
```