# Check if one word follows the other one in the list with python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to count the occurrence of words which are followed by each other in a given list using python.
E.g.

```
my_list = ['ABC', 'DEF', 'PQR', 'ASD', 'ABC', 'DEF', 'ZXC', 'ABC', 'PQR']
```

In the above list, the count of times when `'ABC'` is followed by `'DEF'` is `2`.

Kindly help me out.
Thanks.

Comment: I think you mean the opposite: `ABC` is followed by `DEF`?

Comment: 3 or 2? there are only 2 occurrences of ABC + DEF.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Yes, sorry you are right.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre wrongly typed 3. the actual count is 2. now its not allowing me to edit.

Comment: you can't edit your own posts? never mind. Done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A not very efficient way to do this might be:

```
count = 0
for first,second in zip(my_list,my_list[1:]):
    if first == 'ABC' and second == 'DEF':
        count += 1
```

Or in a *one-liner* using [`sum(..)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=sum#sum):

```
count = sum(1 for first,second in zip(my_list,my_list[1:]) if first == 'ABC' and second == 'DEF')
```

Or as @khelwood says, you can exploit the fact that [`int(..)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=sum#int) of a boolean returns `0` and `1`:

```
count = sum(first == 'ABC' and second == 'DEF' for first,second in zip(my_list,my_list[1:]))
```

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: I was just thinking the same ;)

Comment: You can use `sum` better than that. `sum(first=='ABC' and second=='DEF' for first, second in zip(my_list, my_list[1:]))`

Comment: @khelwood: that's actually a nice hack, I like it :)

Answer (score 3):

A *straightforward* way that does not involve creating an extra slice for pairwise iteration would be to simply use indexes:

```
sum(1 for index in range(len(my_list) - 1) 
    if my_list[index] == 'ABC' and my_list[index + 1] == 'DEF')
```

Or, a bit shorter (thanks to @khelwood):

```
sum(my_list[index] == 'ABC' and my_list[index + 1] == 'DEF' 
    for index in range(len(my_list) - 1))
```

---

Or, without `sum()` and expanded:

```
c = 0
for index in range(len(my_list) - 1):
    if my_list[index] == 'ABC' and my_list[index + 1] == 'DEF':
        c += 1
```

Or:

```
c = 0
for index in range(len(my_list) - 1):
    c += my_list[index] == 'ABC' and my_list[index + 1] == 'DEF'
```

Related materials for one versus the other:

- [Python built-in sum function vs. for loop performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24578896/python-built-in-sum-function-vs-for-loop-performance)
- [Speed of "sum" comprehension in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35191815/speed-of-sum-comprehension-in-python)