# Optimizing dictionary loop summing values

Tags: python, algorithm, performance, optimization, python-2.x

I have a method that takes a nested dict `input_dict`

```
final = 0
for key, value in input_dict[self.state][self.city].iteritems():
    age = self._get_age(key)
    if (age > 0 and age < MAX_VAL):
      final += value  * self.lookup[key][age] * self.multiplier

return final
```

This runs in around .03 seconds, but given that in an example execution it gets called >10k times, it winds up being bottleneck and is responsible for about 50% of the runtime. Assuming I can't reduce the total number of times the method is called, does anyone have suggestions on how to improve this?

Comment: correct. This is 2.7

Comment: What does `self._get_age(key)` does?

Comment: Takes a date `period`: 

`return (self.current_period - period) / 7`

Comment: Where is period the key?

Comment: `input_dict` has keys which are dates, so each key is the argument to `self._get_age(key)`

Comment: how big is your dict?

Comment: <100 key/value pairs

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps consider something like the following-

```
current_period = self.current_period - (self.current_period % 7)
MIN_VALUE = current_period - 7 * MAX_VALUE
return self.multiplier * sum(value * self.lookup[key][self._get_age(key)]
    for key, value in input_dict[self.state][self.city].iteritems()
    if MIN_VALUE < key < current_period
)
```

Here I pull the multiplication by `self.multiplier` out of the loop, and replace the comparison `0 < age < MAX_VALUE` with an equivalent comparison of precomputed values, obtained by substituting `age` with your `_get_age()` method described in the comments and solving for `key`. This allows us to skip the function call + extra computations for cases where `age <= 0 or age >= MAX_VALUE`, and incurs no extra cost (save for computing the 2 variables outside the loop) over the original if `0 < age < MAX_VALUE`. Additionally, this allows us to make use of the builtin `sum()` function, which is typically faster than summing via a for loop, but without creating a separate generator as in qxz's answer.

Note that I assume `(self.current_period - period)` in your `_get_age()` method is an integer, and so `/ 7` floors the result in Python-2.x. If this is not the case, remove the `- (self.current_period % 7)` from the `current_period` assignment for equivalent functionality.

Answer (score -1):

The [built-in `sum` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum) is typically faster than writing out a `for` loop. (See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24578896/1848578).) In your case, you could construct a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions) of the values to be summed, and then pass that to `sum`:

```
items = (
    (key,value,self._get_age(key))
    for key,value in input_dict[self.state][self.city].iteritems()
)
return sum(
    value * self.lookup[key][age] * self.multiplier
    for key,value,age in items
    if 0 < age < MAX_VAL
)
```

Comment: I believe you could use chained comparison, do not know if it will be faster, but is more *pythonic*

Comment: Well, `sum` is generally fast when using it on built-in data-types, generator expressions are typically slow. I bet a for-loop is faster.

Comment: Maybe replacing the generator expressions with list comprehension would be faster?

Comment: That would not scale well, you have to  build  *a list*. Although I think it will be faster for even moderately smalish list sizes, e.g. thousands or even ten thousands. However, then you add linear space complexity to something that can take constant space. Might not be an issue...