# How to run dataframe faster than "for"?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to go through the `TimeStamp` column of a dataframe (row by row). This dataframe has approximately 40,000,000 rows. I'm doing this with `for`, it's working. However, it takes a long time. I wonder if you have something faster.

```
index   TimeStamp             FAILURE MESSAGE
0       2018-01-01 00:00:00   'DOOR OPEN'
1       2018-01-01 00:00:01   'DOOR OPEN'
2       2018-01-01 00:00:02   'DOOR OPEN'
```

Code:

```
cont = 0
for i in range(0, len(df)):
    if(df['TimeStamp'].iloc[i] >= '2018-01-01 00:00:01'):
        cont +=1
```

Comment: `len(df[df['TimeStamp'] >= pd.Timestamp('2018-01-01 00:00:01')].index)`. You should almost never iterate over a dataframe in pandas.

Answer (score 1):

I would do

```
(df['Timestamp'] >= pd.Timestamp('2018-01-1 00:00:01')).sum()
```

Pandas is optimized such that you generally don't need to loop over it

Comment: Don't use the built-in `sum` function on pandas / numpy data structures, that defeats the whole point, because that will essentially be a python level for-loop

Comment: Answer edited to use the series sum but the statement that the sum function is a for loop is incorrect, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24578896/python-built-in-sum-function-vs-for-loop-performance

Comment: i said 'essentially' because it still has to use a Python iterator, whereas `numpy`/`pandas` does not.

Comment: I haven't tested this personally but my understanding is that it's using optimized c code and not just a python iterator.  That stackoverflow post suggests there's a pretty non trivial difference in performance between the two.  So I don't think it's fait to make that claim